# Broadcast rootscope change

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-devtools, rootscope

I'm trying to write a script to access the rootscope and change a variables value from the dev tools. I can get the scope and the rootscope, but my changes don't show up in my bindings. However if I use a bound input everything is fine.

Example:

```
<input ng-model="mode"></input>
<span ng-bind-html="mode"></span>
```

update each other fine but

```
angular.element("body").scope().$root.mode = 'test'
```

Updates the controller but has no effect on the bindings. I have compared my original controller and my console controller using === and they are equal.

So from what I read I need to broadcast or emit that I've changed the scope, however I can't seem to figure out what to broadcast , or if I am broadcasting correctly.

Broadcast code attempts:

```
scope.$apply(function() {root.$emit('change', {mode: 1})})
scope.$apply(function() {root.$emit('stateChangeSuccess', {mode: 1})})
root.$apply(function() {root.$emit('change', {mode: 1})})
root.$apply(function() {root.$emit('stateChangeSuccess', {mode: 1})})
```

Additionally it should be noted that changing the input will change the span but not my copy of the root scope.

```
root.mode = 'console'
type 'input text' in the input
root.mode returns 'console'
```

Comment: You should just need to run a digest cycle after you update the value from "outside of angular". Put angular.element("body").scope().$root.$apply(); after your update. This will trigger a digest cycle and have angular get the View and Model in sync. No need to $emit changes if you aren't subscribing (via scope.$on) to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with events (perhaps I'm wrong). There is another way to do make changes from the console though.

The reason `angular.element("body").scope().$root.mode = 'test'` doesn't update your bindings is that Angular doesn't "know" that a change to the scope has been made. If you are making updates to your data model from "outside" the Angular world, you will need to wrap you changes in an `$apply()` function:

```
var $rootScope = angular.element("body").scope().$root;
$rootScope.$apply(function() {
  $rootScope.mode = 'hi';
});
```

FYI, when sending an event from the `$rooteScope`, you'll want to use [`$broadcast`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) instead of [`$emit`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit). `$broadcast` broadcasts an event "downward" to all descendant scopes, while `$emit` sends the event "upwards" to ancestor scopes. If you `$emit` from the `$rootScope`, there are no ancestor scopes to pick up the event (though perhaps the `$rootScope` will?).

Comment: Still no luck, though I may have a different issue since looking at it again I should note that changing my input fails to update the root.mode, instead root.mode holds the last value I set from the console.

Comment: the `mode` variable probably isn't coming from your $rootScope, but a descendant scope that is created for your controller. If that's the case, then making changes to the $rootScope won't have any effect, since angular will be looking at the descendant scope value of mode. It might be helpful to read up on how scope inheritance work: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: I must have broken something with my testing or had a typo, I refreshed and ran your code one more time and it worked. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, scope() === $root, otherwise you're making some false assumptions here.

WHat I believe is happening is that you are changing value of root scope but your bindings are actually using another scope due to prototype inheritance(eg the string property is actually created in scope() when you bind against it).

Try either of these two tricks:

1) Either try `scope.$apply(function(){scope.mode ='test'});`

2) `$root.mode={name:'test'};` and bind against mode.name in html

Notice that you should be able to fire a $digest cycle using $apply on root scope and it should propagate down to child scopes too. `$root.$apply();`

Comment: scope is a descendant of root. What I had checked with === was root (as generated from the controller creation and put in the window object) vs the root I got after with the angular.element("body").scope().$root.

Comment: Let me put it this way: how exactly do you print out the current value of <input ng-model='mode'/> using console? I still don't understand why do you expect root scope changes to be propagated to child scopes, if dealing with primitive types(strings, ints).. scope().mode should get the real value of what <input text> is binded against.